# Play framework 2.6.3 Application initialization

Tags: scala, playframework

I started to use Play 2.6.3 with Scala. In my project, there are some configuration settings should be set like client, some configuration numbers. When I research it, I found the GlobalSettings but it is removed from Play 2.6.3. My question is I should set a Client class, if the initialization is fine, then start my whole application.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalSettings are deprecated from 2.5.x and may be will be removed later. If you want to change or add some configuration you should write Custom Application Loader. Refer https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.3/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader